# How to cross check if data is present in the database using ajax method?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is the JavaScript code which checks for the validation of the mobile number data (with other data) and forwards it to **validate_user.php** which stores the mobile number.
But I want to store the data of only those users whose mobile number exists in another table or else I want to display an error message saying *'User not present in the database'*.

I need help. What do I do?

Thanks in advance.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#user_submit_form").submit(function() {
        var user_data = $("#user_submit_form").serialize();
        var mobile = new Array();
        mobile = $('#mobile').val().split("");

        if (mobile.length != 10 || !(mobile[0] == 7 || mobile[0] == 8 || mobile[0] == 9)) {
            alert('Please enter a valid mobile number');
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "validate_user.php",
                data: user_data,
                dataType: "json",
            }); // End ajax method
            alert('Thank You');
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

**This is the server side PHP code:**

```
<?php 
session_start();

require("config/config.php"); 

    if(isset($_POST['user_submit']))

             $mobile =mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['mobile']); 
             $dob = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dob']);



$hostname = '';
$database = '';
$username = '';
$password = '';


$conn = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
if(!$conn){
die("Unable to Connect server!".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database!".mysql_error());
 $sql = mysql_query('SELECT mobile FROM mobile_db WHERE mobile="'.$mobile.'"');
                if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1)
                {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO taj_contact_info (chassis,pin,title,fname,lname,email,mobile,dob,anniversary,company,designation,home_business,add1,add2,city,state,pincode,timestamp) VALUES("'.$mobile.'","'.$dob.'",'.strval(time()).')';

            $sql1= mysql_query($query); 
                }
                    else
                        {
                            return true;
                        }



?>
```

Comment: use the success callback of ajax request and set logic regarding response returned by server. You should be able by searching to find hundred of duplicates of similar question...

Comment: any code that you tried on server side?

Comment: as you have a ajax method so you have to check it on server side `php` as you have your environment and there you have to do your logic then return your message to your ajax method and show that in your ajax callback.

Comment: Does your server-side code work? Do you have a return for the case where you find the mobile number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#user_submit_form").submit(function() {
        var user_data = $("#user_submit_form").serialize();
        var mobile = new Array();
        mobile = $('#mobile').val().split("");

        if (mobile.length != 10 || !(mobile[0] == 7 || mobile[0] == 8 || mobile[0] == 9)) {
            alert('Please enter a valid mobile number');
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "validate_user.php",
                data: user_data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(json){
                if(json.error){
                   alert(json.error)// or do whatever you want
                    }
                else{
                   alert(json.success) // there your made a success call the do your staff
                    }
                  }
            }); // End ajax method
            alert('Thank You');
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
});


**The Server Side php**

    <?php 
session_start();

require("config/config.php"); 

    if(isset($_POST['user_submit']))

             $mobile =mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['mobile']); 
             $dob = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dob']);



$hostname = '';
$database = '';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$json = array();

$conn = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
if(!$conn){
$json['error'] = "Unable to Connect server!".mysql_error();
}
if(empty($json)){
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database!".mysql_error());
 $sql = mysql_query('SELECT mobile FROM mobile_db WHERE mobile="'.$mobile.'"');
                if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1)
                {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO taj_contact_info (chassis,pin,title,fname,lname,email,mobile,dob,anniversary,company,designation,home_business,add1,add2,city,state,pincode,timestamp) VALUES("'.$mobile.'","'.$dob.'",'.strval(time()).')';

            $sql1= mysql_query($query);
            $json['success'] = "Successfully inserted"; 
                }
                    else
                        {
                            $json['error'] = 'A Fake Number';
                        }
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can verify this using success response

```
$.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "validate_user.php",
                data: user_data,
                dataType: "json",
                success:(function(result){
                       if(empty(result)){
                          return false;
                       }else{
                         return true;
                       }
                 }));

            });
```